# Is there anything more reliable than $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, raphael

I have a utility that draws a simple arc, either using SVG or, as a fallback, Canvas.  (An early version can be found in my [Raphael Arcs Project](http://elfsternberg.com/projects/raphael_arcs/arc_both.html) on my website.

To accomodate a mobile solution, I recently added code to monitor the size of the container and, if it changes, to re-draw the image to fit the newly sized container.  This addition uses only the size of the containing DIV; the code adds either a SVG or Canvas object to the DIV.

Repeatedly reloading the page, however, sometimes the DIV layout isn't ready even when `$(document).ready` says it is.  This seems to be most prevalent under Chrome; I've seen it only once with Opera and never with Firefox 3.6.  The height and width of the containing DIV come back as zero.

If you load the link above in Chrome and hit reload, every tenth hit or so the Canvas demo will show a similar flaw: it will be sized width: 100% of viewport, height: 300px, and the demo will not draw correctly.

I've looked through the jQuery documentation and it seems to insist that `$(document).ready()` ought to be enough.  I'd rather not have 12% of my users experience a browser-related failure.  Other than writing my own layout probe (a spinning Timeout asking, over and over, "is the container sized yet?"), is there a common technique or library to assure that not only is the DOM loaded but the layout manager has settled?

[EDIT]

I've ended up doing something like this (code is Coffeescript):

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('.wrapper').each ->
        demo = =>
            c = new CanvasArc $('.canvas_demo', this)
            c.sweep(1.0)
            r = new RaphaelArc $('.raphael_demo', this)
            r.sweep(1.0)
        scan = =>
            if $('.canvas_demo', this).height()
                demo()
            else
                setTimeout(scan, 100)
        scan()
```

I really shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: `window.onload` `.ready` does not wait for images.

Comment: @Raynos - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @JasCav but if you read his actual question he's actually asking wait for canvas/svg to finish loading, which is different from images ;) I don't know whether `.onload` will work for fixing canvas/svg

Comment: @Raynos - Ooo...good point. Reading comprehension fail for me. :-p

Comment: It's not even that.  It's that the DIV into which I want to append a <canvas> or <svg> tag isn't sized yet even though ```.ready``` has fired, which leads to the drawing surface having zero dimensions.

Comment: @ElfSternberg my point was `onload` fires after `ready`. See whether using `onload` fixes your problem. Alternatively detect for the `load` event on the `<div>` but that has poor browser support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that you shouldn't have to work around this. The answer is hidden in the [.ready() section](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

So all you need to do is include your CSS first and then your scripts. This way, your ready-event handler isn't even being set until after the CSS has been loaded.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to have worked; putting the <link> tag for the stylesheets *above* the <script> tag seems to have made the problem go away for Chrome.  That makes no sense whatsoever, but I accept it.

Comment: It makes all the sense in the world. It needs to know how to draw things before you can check the heights of them.  As a general rule, load scripts very last.

Comment: In addition, many people recommend putting the `<script>` tag in the footer, to speed up perceived page loading times.

Comment: The browser has to apply your styles before it can tell you the dimensions of styled elements. So load your styles first! :)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `$(document).ready` is that it fires as soon as the DOM is ready for manipulation, without having to wait for all the images to download. If you need images to have downloaded, you should attach to the regular `onload` event. If you're adding images dynamically, you may be able to [attach to the `onload` event of an Image object](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called) and do some stuff then.

Comment: Nick, I'm not downloading images.  I'm using the Canvas and SVG to render graphs, charts, and other vector art using data already present in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`ready` is an event that signifies that the DOM is ready for scripting—that is, all elements exist with their basic properties and you can add/remove elements, etc.—but not that all the elements have rendered. Use `window.onload` (`load` in jQuery) if you want to be sure that all "loaded assets" have completely finished loading all content, including images and possibly other embedded content that takes time to load.

[jQuery's ready page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) says:

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets, the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

Are any of the contents of the `div` that you are looking at "loaded assets"? If so, then their loading can change the size of the `div` after the `ready` event. Theoretically, you then should be able to use `asset.load` to respond as soon as a particular loaded asset has finished downloading. Use `document.ready` to wire up this event.

Comment: As already mentioned, I am not downloading images.  This has nothing to do with the IMG tag.  This has to do with the CANVAS and SVG tags.  I agree they should "exist with their basic properties," including their height and width, when ```.ready``` fires.  In Chrome, that's not happening reliably.

Comment: @Elf, ErikE said "but not that all the elements have rendered."  I wouldn't expect width and height to be set if the element isn't rendered yet.  Try `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't rely on the script to size your div, but rather let him size via CSS, with a percentage width, this way on document ready it will be already sized.

Comment: The DIV *is* sized via CSS.  Because I don't know the capability of the browser, I have to wait until ```.ready``` to determine capability (I'm using Modernizr), then add the CANVAS or SVG to the DIV, using the size of the DIV to set the size of the drawing surface.  Despite being set with CSS, I'm still occasionally getting a height, width of 0, 0  even after ```.ready``` fires.